# Use function preg_replace to replace period with paragraph

Tags: php, string, wordpress, str-replace

I have a lot of unformatted text in my WP posts; i tried to use this code:

```
function user_content_replace($content) {
    return str_replace('.','.</p><p>',$content);
}
add_filter('the_content','user_content_replace', 99);
```

So in fact i want to replace PERIOD with PARAGRAPH and PERIOD (`.</p><p>`)

But I need a little bit help here: first - this code replaces EVERY DOT, so all my permalinks, image paths, etc. are substituted with DOT and that is bad, web does not work at all in this case.

So, i think that solution to replace EVERY THIRD DOT will be salvation for me, so not every DOT.

Any ideas?

Thanx

EDIT:

I changed code above and edit core post-template.php file inside wp-includes folder:

```
function the_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false) {
    $content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    $content = preg_replace('/([^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]*){1}\\.([^\\.]*)/s', '$1.</p><p>$2',$content);
    echo $content;
}
```

And it is ok for now, most of text is grammatical correct, problem now is that above expression changed IMAGES PATH, so instead **something.com/wp-content/image.jpg** I have - something.com/wp-content/

image.

jpg

Any ideas regarding this?

**NOTICE:**

Hmm, code works yesterday, but today does not work. Nothing is changed in code , but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: there are so many cases where this will  fail, its not worth trying to change grammar this way

Comment: @Dagon OK, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Thank you, but to use human on 120 thousands posts is a little bit morbid, don't you think? Anyway, I asked for advice from programmer, not copywriters manager :)

Comment: An idea: use an HTML parser and then replace only the text node content.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Could you elaborate a little bit, please?

Comment: You receive the input. Then, you use an X/HTML parser. With it, you look for all text nodes and replace it's content. You then show the result.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - only one thing - when you say "replace it's content" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that you replace the content of the text node. I'm over-over-simplifying it here. I'm not going to write the code. Just saying how I would do.

Comment: I don't need a code, but I will probably stay within code above. I have 120k of posts, so XML parsing of this content and writing a code is a full-time job and I don't have a time for it. My question above is simple for someone who knows PHP better then me: I need to replace EVERY THIRD DOT, that is all.

Comment: Basically, you search for textnodes with xpath (`//text()`), then you process them through a loop. It remains a hard work: you have to check the node tag (it can be `<title>`, `<p>`, `<b>`, ...) and to act accordingly (you can limit xpath query on `<p>` descendants, but some problem remains). Also you have to consider approach for `A. Smith`, `...`, `0.5`, `N.B.C.`, `e.g.`, etc...

Comment: @fusion3k Thank you, that is a very good answer - but tell me if above function works for me, just replaces EVERY PERIOD, what I need is a function which replaces every third period. This would be a very nice solution for me in this moment. Maybe you know or have an idea how to make this?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to replace EVERY THIRD DOT, that is all

Code sample:

```
$content = "first.sec\nond.third.fourth.fifth>.sixth].seventh.";
$replacement = '$1.</p><p>$2';
echo preg_replace("/([^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]*){1}\\.([^\\.]*)/s", $replacement, $content);
echo "\n";
```

Output of the above code:

```
first.sec
ond.third.</p><p>fourth.fifth>.sixth].</p><p>seventh.
```

Comment: Man it works like a charm, there is some grammar errors, but nothing serious. I just incorporate your regex to my code, you are really quick :)

Only one problem - I don't know how much you or anyone here knows about wordpress - I need this only to be implemented within POST content; now my images does not work - image path is changed to:

http://cdn.printfriendly.com/button-print grnw20.</p><p>png

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, now I think I have enough stackoverflow points to post comments :D

About the issue you mentioned, one possible solution is that you can detect first if the content is a URL or not, for example:

if (filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { /* URL, don't do it */ } else { /* Not a URL, do it */ }

Comment: Could you please write me some dummy code example? I did not work with image filter before?

Comment: @Dagon I don't have "M.D.", "D.C.", "...", "$9.99", "8:00 a.m" this kind of text anywhere in my blog, so I am not doomed, everything works well, more then I imagined; except - how to exclude images URL's from expression

Comment: @OnlineSid Thank you man. I tried exactly the same code, with some addons - nothing; tried also your code here - also the same problem - images does not load properly.

In every image URL period is replaced with `code`.</p><p>`code`

So every image url looks like [link](http://example.</p><p>/image.</p><p>jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with some manual string iteration:

```
$text = 'text.with.dots.text.with.dots.text.with.dots';
function user_content_replace($content) {
    $str_parts = explode('.', $content);
    $result = '<p>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($str_parts); $i++) {
      $result .= $str_parts[$i];
      if (($i + 1) % 3 === 0)
          $result .= '.</p><p>';
      else
          $result .= '.';
    }
    $result .= '</p>';
    return $result;
}
```

However, as the comments noted, this is hardly accurate (eg. if one dot has been forgotten). There's a reason why shortcodes are popular, and that is because it's much easier to accurately manipulate string contents with these, also when used as boundaries. Eg, you could do like below:

```
$better = '[myTag]text.with.dots[/myTag][myTag]text.with.dots[/myTag][myTag]text.with.dots[/myTag]';
function user_content_replace2($content) {
    $result = preg_replace('/\[myTag\]/', '<p>', $content);
    $result = preg_replace('/\[\/myTag\]/', '</p>', $result);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I edited my question above, I know about grammatic issues, but this is not a problem at all, code works like a charm, but it also edited images paths?!

Comment: Hmm, code works yesterday, but today does not work. Nothing is changed, but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I used your code now, because my does not work anymore?!?! Do yo have any suggestion how to exclude urls from your code above @Tyblitz

Comment: @Eager2Learn What do you mean "does not work"? All this code does is split a string on dots, replace every third dot with a `p` tag, and keep the others as dots. Ofc. as I mentioned this (and any solution based on such algorythm) *"is hardly accurate"*. Are your URL's enclosed in `<img>` or `<a>` tags ?

Comment: could you help me with this image issue?

Comment: @Eager2Learn sorry I can't. This was not part of the initial question and would require a function much more complex and time-consuming, as well as never accurate as the approach is flawed in itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct and working answer to my question:

```
function user_content_replace($content) {

$sentences_per_paragraph = 3; // settings

$pattern = '~(?<=[.?!…])\s+~'; // some punctuation and trailing space(s)

$sentences_array = preg_split($pattern, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // get sentences into array

$sentences_count = count($sentences_array); // count sentences

$output = ''; // new content init

// see PHP modulus
for($i = 0; $i < $sentences_count; $i++) {
    if($i%$sentences_per_paragraph == 0 && $i == 0) { //divisible by settings and is first
        $output .= "<p>" . $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // add paragraph and the first sentence
    } elseif($i%$sentences_per_paragraph == 0 && $i > 0) { //divisible by settings and not first
        $output .= "</p><p>" . $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // close and open paragraph, add the first sentence
    } else {
        $output .= $sentences_array[$i] . ' '; // concatenate other sentences
    }
}

$output .= "</p>"; // close the last paragraph

echo $output;
}
add_filter('the_content','user_content_replace', 99);
```

Above answers was only partial and does not suit WordPress code hierarchy. Also they caused images URL problem and I do not recommend that approach to problem explained in my question. Thank you all for your help.